# After ee update custom links doesn't work anymore

Tags: navigation

the title described it.
After the ee update i wasn't able to click on my custom links in the ee main bar anymore.
It throw me always out of my login session.
I had to re-add each of my custom links to get it working.

**UPDATE:** I updated from 4.3.3 to 4.4.5. The behaviour was the same in an older update i did before. I added the links always via your +Add button and after an update, these links always fail.
I think it's because a session or id is saved also inside the links. For example here is one of my old ones...

```
http://url.de/backend/index.php?S=56ddd7c4744a94b131bcd8f0bdb6f61965476ed5&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=zenbu
```

I always login via /system/ or in this example via /backend/ instead of admin.php, because there were always some issues in the past, but i can't remember by now.

Is there any other solution for this?

Thanks

Peter

Comment: We need more info: What were the previous links' URLs? What are they now? Do you login from /admin.php or from the system folder? Did you always login from there? What version did you update from and to?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the sessions are handled differently in the most recent versions of EE.

I fixed it on a couple of sites of mine just by recreating the links. If you're still having issues then I'd suggest removing the session hash from the URL.

So
    http://url.de/backend/index.php?S=56ddd7c4744a94b131bcd8f0bdb6f61965476ed5&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=zenbu

Would become
    http://url.de/backend/index.php?cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=zenbu